# Does error reported in running java program refer to mistake in database or to something in my code?

Tags: sqlite, exception

I am confused by an error message that used to work in the program I borrowed my code from. I thought I understood the error message, having seen and fixed others like it before:
"Data Update failed: org.sqlite.SQLiteException. [SQLITE_ERROR]SQL error or missing database (near " ": syntax error)
I thought this meant that in the database being called there was a syntax error near a pair of double quotation marks with a space in between them. However, double-checking my .db file I find there are no such pairs of quotation marks whatsoever. Looking over the related code in Java. there also is no such pair of quotation marks with nothing between them.

It would help to be sure whether the error message applies to my sqlite database or not.

It's been a long time, but if memory serves, in the past I would get a pop-up message about some error near the word "rover," I would scan over my DB looking for rover and there I would find messed up coding.

I'm stumped.

I've checked through the Java syntax via Google and have not found anything definite about what document the offending SQL_ERROR is supposed to be found in.
I've run a copy of my own code through BBEdit to kill any gremlins, but none have been found.
I have exported the DB, opened it with Macintosh "Numbers," copied our the resulting table and pasted it into a dead simple text editor that will let me save it as txt, and I have searched for: " " but  none were found.

```
    JButton btnB1 = new JButton("Update");
    btnB1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String query= "Update grist set EID  ='"+ txtCS.getText()+"', retvd ='"+ txtrVD.getText()+"', retve ='"+ txtrVE.getText()+"', retvf ='"+ txtrVF.getText()+"',  retvg ='"+ txtrVG.getText()+"', retvh ='"+ txtrVH.getText()+"', retvj ='"+ txtrVJ.getText()+"', retvk ='"+ txtrVK.getText()+"', retvm ='"+ txtrVM.getText()+"', retvn ='"+ txtrVN.getText()+"', retvp ='"+ txtrVP.getText()+"', retvq ='"+ txtrVQ.getText()+"'.  retvr ='"+ txtrVR.getText()+"',  retvs ='"+ txtrVS.getText()+"',  ";
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);                     
                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Updated");
                pst.close();
            }catch (Exception g) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Update failed: " + g);
            }
            refreshTable();                         
        }
    });
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnB1, -140, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frame.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnB1, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, btnB4);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btnB1, 14, SpringLayout.EAST, txtrVN);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnB1);
```

Comment: Your update statement ends with `,`. Remove it.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you very much. (There is also a period where a comma should be. My eyes were not good enough to notice that typo.) Thank you very much.